# REST api: How can I make sure that client has received all data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 app with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have a method with this signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Models.ExternalCodes> GetCodes(
    ExternalCodesQueryData queryData)
{
    // ...
}
```

Is there any method to make sure that client has received all data?

Maybe HTTP protocol has some mechanics to allow this. Maybe is data received by client is corrupt, you client can't read it.

Comment: Dispatch a guy to their house to ask if they got the data.

Comment: @Dan-o Today is the day of humor. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you control the client?
If so, you can simply have the client call back to the webapi with a "Hey, the data you sent over arrived in one piece."

Though this mechanism is of *very* limited usefulness.
HTTP is sent over TCP which is fault-tolerant and error-correcting.  So unless something catastrophic happens, like the connection unexpectedly closing, you can assume that all the data arrived in one piece.